# Simple method to return comma-separated values of object array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object that looks like this:

```
{
  "id": "123",
   "members": [
     { "id": 1, "name": "Andrew" },
     { "id": 2, "name": "Jim" }
   ]
}
```

I'd like a method to return a string of member names: `"Andrew, Jim"`.

As opposed to iterating through the member list and adding them to an array, is there a way to accomplish this cleanly in a single line (maybe underscore.js)?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`members` is `Array` of `Objects`, first you need to create `Array` with names - for this case you can use [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and then convert this `Array` to `String` - to do that you can use [`.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```js
var data = {
  "id": "123",
   "members": [
     { "id": 1, "name": "Andrew" },
     { "id": 2, "name": "Jim" }
   ]
};

var result = data.members.map(function (e) {
  return e.name;
}).join(', ');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Exact answer as per my requirement. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

something like

```
var arr = {
  "id": "123",
   "members": [
     { "id": 1, "name": "Andrew" },
     { "id": 2, "name": "Jim" }
   ]
};
 console.log( arr.members.reduce( function(x,y){ return "\"" + x.name + "\", \"" + y.name + "\"" } ) );
```